# How to add git-backed distributions for Heroku

Tags: python, git, heroku

How do I add my own private modules to python for Heroku so that my main project can `import` my own custom packages?

**ex.** I have 1) `git` repository that is used for my web app and a 2) others that are not available via `pip`, that I would like to `import` into my main project (1).

Read more here: [Heroku: git-backed distribution](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip#gitbacked-distributions)

Is it better to use [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there something you're trying to do that the guide doesn't explain? It seems to answer all your questions, are you getting errors or something?

Comment: I rephrased the question. Let me know if it makes more sense. But I am able to push my project to heroku, its just he dependancies in the project are other projects that I have created myself, some are public some are private on github.

Comment: Whichever works best for you.

Comment: I would steer clear of git submodules, and either run with git + pip, or run your own private index. I have been done the submodule path for app dependancies and it isn't pretty. We currently run both of my suggested methods, and no reported issues.

Comment: @RhysElsmore can you show my how you accomplish this git + pi and private index? This is in reference to the original question. I'm open to adjusting the question to make it more relevant to this discussion.